# Determine RC to be configured for AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, concurrency, amazon-cloudwatch

How can we determine how many Reserved concurrency should be configured lambda based on cloudwatch metrics .

Will I able to derive using concurrent executions metrics I see in cloudwatch for that lambda